# How to retrieve the amount of GPRS/3G/wifi data uploaded or downloaded from a mobile in android application

Tags: android

I have developing an android application, I have easily retrieved the calllog & SMS Inbox & Sentbox. Now I have to retrieve the amount of  Internet Data(in bytes) which is uploaded or downloaded. Let me know the code

Answer (score 0):

Android API dont give any method by which you can get the amount of Data that has been transferred or downloaded.